# How to connect Paramiko stdin to console?

Tags: python, ssh, pipe, stdin, paramiko

Use the Paramiko package to run commands over SSH. Need to run a app that takes in user input, how can I connect sys.stdin directly to the app that is running via Paramiko so whatever the user types in, it will go into the app running.

```py
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('/tmp/input_required')

while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    print(stdout.read(1), end ='')
```

Comment: Are there arguments to pass in stein and stdout or do you always get the files as output? (Probably not that command, is there another one?)

Comment: No arguments to pass in during init time, during run time, the file "input_required" will be printing statements, and will require user input. Its an interactive application.